# Солдат или солдатов?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "солдат" или "солдатов"?

Например:

> Шесть солдат(ов) идут по шоссе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В русском языке существует много слов, очень похожих по морфологическим признакам, но различающихся при этом падежными формами. Возьмём, к примеру, слова солдат и офицер. Оба сущ. м.р., 2 склонения, одуш, нариц. Но в родительном и винительном падежах они обретают такие формы: солдат - офицерОВ. Нулевая флексия в первом случае и -ов - во втором. К сожалению, приходится лишь запоминать правильную форму и, чтобы лучше запомнилась, чаще проговаривать её. Я, например, всё время кручу в голове фразу: пять килограммов помидоров ))).

Comment: Бедные иностранцы)))

Comment: >>>пять килограммов помидоров  

И напрасно. Счетная форма - "пять килограмм"  как минимум допустима. Что касается "помидор", то в сосбтвенно родительном падеже это пока ненормативно, но можно предположить, что как счетная форма (пять помидор) этот вариант может вытеснить основной.

Comment: Да, мы всегда оговариваем допустимость (я показываю пачку чая с надписью "100 грамм") и о тенденции к изменению формы слова тоже говорим, но, пока варианты борются, пусть крутится "пять килограммов помидоров" ))).

Answer (score 1):

Правильная форма родительного множдественного - солдат. Это не единственное подобное слово.

Я думаю, самое правильное - перенести сюда статью с gramma.ru

Падежные окончания существительных во множественном числе
Cуществительные мужского рода в форме родительного падежа

Многие имена существительные мужского рода в форме родительного падежа множественного числа имеют нулевое окончание, т. е. оканчиваются на согласный основы. Сюда относятся слова, называющие:

парные предметы: (нет) ботинок, валенок, погон, чулок (но: носков), эполет (но: рельсов);

некоторые национальности (у большинства слов основа оканчивается на н и р): (образ жизни) англичан, армян, башкир, болгар, бурят, грузин, лезгин, осетин, румын, туркмен, турок, хазар, цыган; но: бедуинов, калмыков, киргизов, коряков, монголов, негров, орочей, таджиков, тунгусов, узбеков, хакасов, хорватов, чукчей, якутов;

воинские объединения: (отряд) партизан, солдат; в названиях прежних родов войск формы с нулевым окончанием и на ов употребляются дифференцированно, в зависимости от значения: при собирательном значении (с неопределенно-количественными существительными армия, отряд, войско, группа и т. п.) используется форма с нулевым окончанием: (отряд) гренадер, гусар, драгун, кирасир, рейтар (средневековый воин), улан, а при обозначении отдельных лиц (или конкретного количества, названного числительными) - форма на ов: (пять) гусаров, кирасиров; формы гардемарин - гардемаринов равноупотребительны; в названиях современных родов войск употребляется, как правило, полная форма: (группа) минеров, саперов, мичманов;

некоторые единицы измерения: (несколько) ампер, ватт, вольт, аршин, герц, гран, эрстед; наблюдаются колебания следующих счетных форм: микрон - микронов, ом - омов, рентген - рентгенов, грамм - граммов, килограмм - килограммов, карат - каратов; а также формы на ов; кулонов (и кулон), ньютонов (и ньютон), эргов (и эрг), динаров, гектаров.

Как нормативные в языке используются следующие формы на ов: апельсинов, мандаринов, помидоров, томатов; но: баклажан - баклажанов.

Примечания:

~1. При наличии вариантов следует ориентироваться на тенденцию в современном языке к использованию более короткой формы, т. е. с нулевым окончанием.

~2. Необходимо различать формы родительного падежа множественного числа у слов-омонимов; ср.: глазок (у картофеля); им. п., мн. ч. - глазки, род. п., мн. ч. - глазков, а глазок (уменьшительное от глаз) имеет формы: им. п., мн. ч. - глазки, род. п., мн. ч. - глазок; рожки (пищевой продукт): род. п., мн. ч. - рожков, а рожки (уменьшительное от рог) - рожек.